# Getting access to the output of intermediate layers in keras based on the input tensor being fed

Tags: python, computer-vision, keras, keras-layer

[Deep Domain Confusion architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VOb7.png)

I am trying to implement the model proposed in the picture. The idea is to send labeled data and unlabeled data through the model, get access to the intermediate layer output named 'adapt_layer' based on the data (labeled, unlabeled), and calculate custom loss.

I looked into Keras's API and have managed to implement so far:

```
    model = load_model(weight_path)

    inp = model.input
    out = model.layers[-2].output
    adapt_layer = Dense(512, activation='sigmoid', name='adapt_layer')(out)
    preds = Dense(19, activation='softmax', name='predictions', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01))(adapt_layer)
    vision_model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=preds)

    labeled_input = Input(shape=(None, 1024, 1024, 3))
    unlabeled_input= Input(shape=(None, 1024, 1024, 3))

    preds_labeled = vision_model(labeled_input)

    labeled_features = vision_model(labeled_input).layers[-2].output
    unlabeled_features = vision_model(unlabeled_input).layers[-2].output
```

Based on the architecture, we calculate a domain loss between the features of the labeled and unlabeled data, due to which I need access to them. Is there a way to get access to the features with respect to the inputs without making another model and using .predict()?